# Awk to reformat date and other lines

Tags: linux, awk

Please I need to reformat a file of 60,000 lines, and each line in this format:

```
22/02/2016 1234567745678900
```

The first sequence is a date and the next is a number string. I need to, extract both fields as input variables into a shell script, so I can use both to search log files to pull out some data. So that the date is formatted in the way the log files are dated, I need to  modify the date to unix timestamp format so the whole line looks such as

```
2016-02-22
```

Please what is the proper Linux awk incantation to do this, and how does it work so I can replicate next time?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're planning on running other system commands for each line of the file, awk may not be the best tool for the job.

Comment: I want to use awk to format the file lines, then use system commands to finish the job.

Comment: If you explain a little more about what you're trying to do, we can help you better. Depending on how you plan on using the formatted data, it might be more efficient to read the lines in the shell.

Comment: Edited. Is it clear enough for you now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '{gsub("/","-"); print $1,$2,"or",$2,$1}' file
22-02-2016 1234567745678900 or 1234567745678900 22-02-2016
```

**EDIT**: for the updated question

```
$ echo "22/02/2016 1234567745678900" | awk '{ split($1,a,"/"); print a[3] "-" a[2] "-" a[1]}'
2016-02-22
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! How about if I want to convert 22/02/2016 to 2016-02-22?

Comment: Would be grateful for any awk resources I can learn from. It seems amazing.

Comment: Awk is amazing, indeed! To quote frequent contributor Ed Morton, "Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins."

Comment: Thank you! Looking for it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to change the string 22/02/2016 to 22-02-2016 in a file then you can go with VI editor.

```
:%s/22\/02\/2016/22-02-2016/g
```

It will find the string 22/02/2016 and change to 22-02-2016

Comment: Thanks but there are 60,000 lines. I need to do this as fast and as efficiently as possible.